# Why does my .Net runtimeconfig.json reference the 6.0.8 runtime instead of 6.0.0?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a solution with an ASP.Net API project and a few ConsoleApp projects (webjobs) that get deployed to an Azure App Service. For this solution, on the build machine the resulting API.runtimeconfig.json references the 6.0.8 runtime, whereas all other similar solutions (and we have lots) reference 6.0.0 and roll forward at runtime. This is a problem because the App Services don't yet have the 6.0.8 runtime, so the API will not launch. There are ways to work around this problem, but I want to fix it - to understand why this particular project references 6.0.8.

Building this solution locally (Win10, Rider 2022.2, .Net SDK 6.0.400) produces 6.0.0 in the API.runtimeconfig.json, as expected. The build machine is an Azure DevOps Pipeline Agent (Ubuntu). The YAML build command is;

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '--no-restore /p:configuration="$(buildConfiguration)" /p:DeployOnBuild=false /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"'
```

The .csproj for the API project has;

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
<RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

The .csproj for the ConsoleApp projects has;

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
<RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

The win-x64 RuntimeIdentifier is specified in the ConsoleApp project files because the build machine is Linux but the runtime machine is Windows and we run the webjobs via an exe.

None of our solutions use runtimeconfig.template.json.

I've spent hours Googling and comparing this solution to a number of other working solutions and can't see any differences that appear relevant. Given the same build machines build all the other working solutions I'm assuming it's something about the solution, but what am I missing?